# Create a procedure to merge data and avoid duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a SQL Server merge procedure that would allow me to merge new entries in the data set and nullify duplicates in the table. Both tables of the same type. I am trying to perform a merge and avoid duplicates. The ID and Email will always be a one to one relation. However, the source table sometimes will send the same email with two different Ids.  We want to keep only one record per person and nullify all the email for the invalid record. Initial thoughts are to join the source table with the target table on email and check which emails have two occurrences and nullify, but how could I put this in one procedure.

Table 1 and Table 2:

```
Id | Email | First  | Last | Building | Date |....
```

Example of duplicate:

```
1 | tst@tst.com | ...
2 | tst@tst.com | ...
```

Needed output:

```
1 | tst@tst.com
2 | null
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mergingTwo @TableType 
AS 
BEGIN
    MERGE [target]
    USING [source] ON [target].Id = [source].Id OR [target].Email = [source].Email 

    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
       UPDATE 
           SET 

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
       INSERT
```

Comment: You can do a complex and with the matching... `WHEN MATCHED AND [target].id <> [source].id then update set email = null` and so on.... just make sure you account for all of the matching combinations somehow. Here's an example of such a use of MATCHED and.... https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/

Answer (score 1):

Can do the Merge First then nullify the e-mail in a Second update like

```
With cte as (select id, row_number() over (partition by e-mail order by id asc) n_row 
From table_foo)

Update table_foo
Set email = null
From table_foo
Inner Join cte
On cte.id = table_foo.id
And cte.n_row > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for a union (unless you really want those NULL entries).

```
SELECT Email FROM Table1 
UNION
SELECT Email FROM Table2
;
```